# Calculate how long it will take a loop to finish

Tags: c#, performance, loops, for-loop

So I have the following loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numRows + 2; i++) //numRows was +4, now +2
{

  Console.Clear();

  Console.WriteLine("Number of rows: " + numRows);
  Console.Write("Checking Row #: " + currRowNumber);

  //We want to skip every row that is null and continue looping until we have more than 3 rows in a row that are null, then break
  if (i > 1) {
    i -= 1;
  }

  //Create Worksheet Range
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) excelWorkbookWorksheet.Cells[i, 2];
  string cellValue = Convert.ToString(range.Value);

  if (nullCounter == 3) //was 5
  {
    Console.WriteLine("\nNull row detected...breaking");
    Console.WriteLine("Number of rows deleted: " + numRowsDeleted);
    break;
  }

  if (cellValue != null) {
    if (cellValue.Contains(searchText)) {
      //Console.WriteLine("Deleting Row: " + Convert.ToString(cellValue));
      ((Range) excelWorkbookWorksheet.Rows[i]).Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
      numRowsDeleted++;
      //Console.WriteLine("Number of rows deleted: " + numRowsDeleted);
      nullCounter = 0;
      i--;
      currRowNumber++;
      rowsPerSecond = i;
    } else {
      currRowNumber++;
      nullCounter = 0;
    }
  } else {
    nullCounter++;
    //Console.WriteLine("NullCounter: " + nullCounter);
  }
  i++;

}
```

I want to calculate how many rows I'm looping through per second, then calculate from that number how long it will take to complete the entire loop, based on how many rows there are.

Comment: Check out the `StopWatch` class for getting the timings.

Comment: Are you trying to give a percentage complete on the function while it runs? (Otherwise counting how many rows and how long it takes to analyse after, as stated in the answers given works)

Comment: Not necessarily a percentage, but rather an estimated time of how long is left based on rows left/rows per second

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty trivial to get something simple up and running. Consider the following class:

```
public class TimePredictor
{
    private readonly Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    private double currentProgressRate;

    public void Start() => watch.Restart();
    public void Stop() => watch.Stop();
    public double ElapsedTime => watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    public void Update(long currentProgress)
    {
        currentProgressRate = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / (double)currentProgress;
    }

    public double GetExpectedTotalTime(long total)
        => total * currentProgressRate;

    public double GetExpectedTimeLeft(long total)
        => GetExpectedTotalTime(total) - watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

And a trivial use case:

```
var repetitions = 200;
var predictor = new TimePredictor();

predictor.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep((new Random()).Next(100, 250));

    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        predictor.Update(i);
        Console.WriteLine($"Iteration #{i}:");
        Console.WriteLine($"\tExpected total time: {predictor.GetExpectedTotalTime(repetitions) / 1000.0:N1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"\tExpected time left: {predictor.GetExpectedTimeLeft(repetitions) / 1000.0:N1}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

predictor.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Total time: {predictor.ElapsedTime / 1000.0:N1}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out setting up a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) at the beginning of the loop and check its Elapsed property at the end.

Comment: To become a good answer please provide a relevant to the specific problem example. Link only answers (even if it is to MSDN) are not really good answers

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possible solutions:

1. Take the StopWatch and a Counter. Start the sw before you start with looping and increase the counter with ervery loop. At the end of a walktrough of the loop you can divide counter / sw.Elapsed
2. Use a Counter and a Timer with an interval of 1000ms. Increase the counter every time you go though the For-loop. With every tick you get the current Loops / Second.

EDIT: When you are finished with the for-loop stop the Timer and the StopWatch